# Name error in my code

Tags: python

Hey I've got a very simple problem, however all the places i look to fix it don't seem to work. So for school we gotta do this thing where we save user input to an excel file and where i do Mylist.append(phone) i get an error saying phone is not defined. Any idea on how to fix this?

```
#Zacharriah Task 3
import csv
from IPhone import*
from Android import*
import time

def start():
    print('Hello Welcome to the Phone Trouble-Shooter')
    time.sleep(2)
    phone = input('Please input what brand of phone you have')
    if "iphone" in phone:
        print('Your phone has been identified as an Iphone')
    elif "android" in phone:
        print('Your phone has been identifies as an Android')


file = open("Excel_Task_3.csv", "w", newline = "")
fileWrite = csv.writer(file,delimiter = ",")
Mylist = []

Mylist.append(phone)

fileWriter.writerow(Mylist)

file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If code is exactly like posted then `phone` is really not defined where you need it. It is defined in the function's scope but is used outside - so there is no `phone` variable defined there:

```
def start():
    # defined in the function's scope
    phone = input('Please input what brand of phone you have')
    # rest of code


file = open("Excel_Task_3.csv", "w", newline = "")
fileWrite = csv.writer(file,delimiter = ",")
Mylist = []
# Used outside of the function's scope - it is unrecognized here
Mylist.append(phone)
```

What you can do is return a value from `start` and then use it. Something like:

```
def start():
    phone = input('Please input what brand of phone you have')
    # rest of code
    return phone

# rest of code
Mylist = []
Mylist.append(start())
```

Read [Short Description of Python Scoping Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/291978/6400526)

Comment: So to fix do i put def phone under def start?

Comment: See update. Basically you must make sure that the variable exists in the scope you want to use it.

Comment: @Z.Howells -  Great :)

Answer (score 0):

`phone` not defined outside the `start()` function.

Here: `Mylist.append(phone)`

You should fix it.

Optional fix:

```
def start():
    print('Hello Welcome to the Phone Trouble-Shooter')
    time.sleep(2)
    phone = input('Please input what brand of phone you have')
    if "iphone" in phone:
        print('Your phone has been identified as an Iphone')
    elif "android" in phone:
        print('Your phone has been identifies as an Android')
    return phone # Add this.


file = open("Excel_Task_3.csv", "w", newline = "")
fileWrite = csv.writer(file,delimiter = ",")
Mylist = []
phone = start()  # Add this.
Mylist.append(phone)

fileWriter.writerow(Mylist)

file.close()
```

Comment: You just need to make sure to return phone from the start function you declared above it.

Comment: also be sure to use the return value(phone) later on, when you call the `start()` function at first.